# What is the status, antiquity, authorship, etc. of the Lakshminarayana Samhita?

Tags: sampradaya, author

The Lakshminarayana Samhita seems to be a very large text in Sanskrit. I would like to know who the author is and what is the sampradaya that it espouses.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lakshminarayana-samhita-sanskrit

The above site gives some information but the authorship, etc. is not stated. It seems to be of the  Swami Narayana Sampradaya.